# See if any radio button is checked out of several

Tags: jquery

**Task:**
There are four radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="version" class="radio" value="1" id="a">
```

I need to check if any one of them is selected.

**What I have tried:**

```
if ($("input[name='version']").prop("checked")){
       alert("checked");
   }
```

**Problem:**

This is working only for the first radio button. If I check other radio buttons, nothing...

***Please help***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), it will return true if any of the elements are checked

```
if ( $("input[name='version']").is(":checked") ) ...
```

or check the length of a selector that matches checked elements

```
if ( $("input[name='version']:checked").length ) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and take `length` to check if the selector returned any element. If length is *zero* then no element is checked otherwise one or more of element is checked.

```
if($("input[name='version']:checked").length)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
if ( $("input[name='version']").is(":checked"))
```

**[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use jquery selector to get all checked radio button with `name='version'` and then check its length. If length is greater than zero, means atleast one radio button is checked.

```
if ($("input[name='version']:checked").length > 0){
       alert("checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are only checking the first element. jQuery finds the first element of `("input[name='version']"` and then calls the function `.prop("checked")` thus it only works for the first one.

This will work better:

```
if ($("input[name='version']").is(":checked")) {
  //Do Something
}
```